# ASP.NET MVC - Remote debugging with build server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, remote-debugging

I'm trying to setup remote debugging with Visual Studio and IIS.

I have 3 computers:
 - my PC with Visual Studio
 - build server
 - production machine with IIS

Build server builds the source from repository and publishes the web site on the production machine (by just replacing files).

I've already setup remote debugger tools on production machine and I can connect to it with Visual Studio.

The problem is that I can't set up any breakpoint because I get the message "No symbols were loaded"

I suppose that this is because my local build is somehow different from what build server does.

Can anyone point me in the right direction ? What to do?

Answer (score 2):

The `.pdb` files and all the `.dll` must be the same (same version) on both the client and the server (the machine you are debuggin on)

Make sure you copy the .PDB file that is generated with your assembly into the same folder on the remote machine